# JavaScript slide show only showing every OTHER image

Tags: javascript, jquery

all,

I am having the strangest problem. I had a slideshow script on my page that worked PERFECTLY until like... ten minutes ago. And NOW the thing is still working, but it's only showing every other image. Strange. It only shows 01.jpg, 03.jpg, 05.jpg, and I cannot fathom why.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Only run everything once the page has completely loaded
        $(window).load(function () {
            var imgs = [
                'Images/Slideshow/02.jpg',
                'Images/Slideshow/03.jpg',
                'Images/Slideshow/04.jpg',
                'Images/Slideshow/05.jpg',
                'Images/Slideshow/06.jpg',
                'Images/Slideshow/01.jpg'];

            var cnt = imgs.length;
            function Slider() {
                $('#imageSlide').fadeOut(5000, function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn(2000);
                });
            }
            $(function () {
                setInterval(Slider, 5000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Again... weirdest thing I've ever seen. Anyone have any clue what this could be about? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I've uploaded it again, and it's only showing the 3 images, AND one them isn't showing up. It's at www.martillos-keep.com. I wonder if it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fadeout + fadein time (5000 + 2000) have to be smaller than the interval timer (5000).

Try this:

```
function Slider() {
    $('#imageSlide').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
$(function () {
    setInterval(Slider, 5000);
});
```

Comment: thanks very much! I sometimes just go completely blind when I'm staring at my own code.

Comment: here's another cycler that's better because you don't have to wait the fadeout http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/9TxED/